# A filter to delete object with a specific variable in array

Tags: javascript

I want to show every task that does not have a propery of `type: "delete"`

```
tasks: [
    { title: "test" , type: "delete"},
    { title: "test" , type: "insert"},
    { title: "test" },
],
```

Something like code below.

```
    this.apiTask.filter(x => !x.type : "delete"))
```

I would appreciate if someone can help

Comment: `this.apiTask.filter(x => x.type !== "delete"))`

Comment: And the problem/question is? You seem to know quite "advanced" things like `Array.prototype.filter` and arrow functions. Just add a comparison to test for the value

Answer (score 1):

you have to check the properties in this way:

```js
tasks: [
    { title: "test" , type: "delete"},
    { title: "test" , type: "insert"},
    { title: "test" },
]

console.log(this.apiTasks.flter(task => task.type !== 'delete'))
// OUTPUT: [
//    { title: "test" , type: "insert"},
//    { title: "test" },
// ]
```

Comment: Is a simple comparison like `!=` really worth an answer? That's some really basic stuff OP should know how to use.

Comment: At least link to a [JavaScript comparison operators documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#comparison_operators) so the OP can learn.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases of above:

- if you want that property "type" should be present and type!="delete"
  then use **this.apiTasks.filter(a=>a.type && a.type!=="delete")**
  *# There will be 1 items #*
- if property existence does not matter
  then use **this.apiTasks.filter(a=>a.type!=="delete")**
  *# there will be 2 items #*
  some extra things-
  you can use lodash library
  existence of a propery can be checked using a.hasOwnProperty("type")